# Simple RESTful API authentication

Tags: api, rest, authentication, single-page-application, restful-authentication

I'm building a single-page web application, fully based on RESTful API. I've seen several topics in that matter, but some things remain unclear for me.

I will need users to log in. Here are some of my ideas:

1. I can send e-mail and password to API and use basic auth. I'm not sure **where should I keep password**, **should it be encrypted** and if so: **how?**
2. Can I use **built-in session** system instead? Is it wrong to use **cookies** directly in the RESTful API? Why is it so popular to send credentials/keys to API itself instead of using cookies?
3. I thought about having **one API key per user**, return it in login action and keep it in localStorage. I guess it's not the greatest idea to have just one key per user?
4. Then, I came up with idea to have **separate `keys` table** and add random keys each time somebody logs in. On logout, the key would go away and no longer be valid. This is more secure than previous idea.

How is it solved in simple projects? I'd like to make it simple but not ridiculously inserure.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly approach is to use the header Authorization in REST. The state of the application must be on the client side with REST and shouldn'a be tied to a particularly client kind (browser with cookies)

I think that this link could be helpful:

- Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful applications : https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

There is also à great question to à similar question here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought about the cookies - they are nice way to pass data in request header, but they are browser-related, which is not flexible enough. I will dive in deeper in the topic and choose your answer if I find it satisfactory :)